# How to enter the input not directly in the code but in some interface sub-window?

Tags: syntax, input

I understand that the question is very basic, but I did not find the answer. Consider the parameters

```
parameter1="value";
parameter2 = 13;
```

Normally, these strings are present in the Mathematica code along the other lines which use these parameters as input. This way, they may be hidden from users. Is it possible to make some graphical interface for entering their values, say some colored box saying "Enter parameter 1:", and the field where the user enters it?

Comment: [`Input`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Input.html)?

Comment: The best way to separate code from data is to organize code in functions (e.g. `Module`), and for bigger code in packages of functions. If you care about users, the best way is to provide a small demo program and a package. The program should  only contain the specification of parameters and calls to functions from the package. Solutions with `InputField` and `FormObject` is cosmetics that can be added on top. But the main point is properly organize the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you wish set up a GUI with `Row`, `Column`, `Checkbox`, `InputField` for example, and others.  Here is a simple `Row` construct for a Boolean variable `diagFlag1` and an input field `maxNum`.  First initialize these variables in an Initialization Group (Cell/CellProperties/Initialization Group from Menu) which is initialized  upon starting the notebook.  This will initialize the variables to a default value such as:

```
maxNum=10;
diagFlag1=False;
```

Then code the following.  Next,collapse the actual code and only show the GUI by clicking on the cell border on the right side;

```
Row[{Style["Max number: ", Bold, Black], 
  InputField[Dynamic@maxNum, FieldSize -> 2], 
  Spacer[10], Style["Diagnostic Flag 1 ", Bold, Black], 
  Checkbox[Dynamic@diagFlag1]}]
```

From here it's easy to add more items such as using `Column` for a matrix of values and the `Dynamic@variable` construct updates the value of the variable as soon as you enter it into the fields without having to re-run anything or press an enter key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FormObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormObject.html) and [`FormFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html).

Create your form.

```
form =
  FormFunction[
   FormObject[{
     {"parameter1", "Parameter 1:"} -> "String"
     , {"parameter2", "Parameter 2:"} -> "Number"
     }
    , AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Enter Parameters"|>]
   ];
```

Activate `form` and capture the results in `params`.

```
params = form[];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

When Submit button is clicked `params` will be filled with the [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) of values.

```
params
```

> ```
> <|"parameter1" -> "Hi there", "parameter2" -> 21.1|>
> ```

Access values as normal with associations.

```
params["parameter1"]
```

> ```
> "Hi there"
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! It often stuck: instead of showing the dialog window, it outputs `Forms`PackageScope`bindForm(FormObject[<|parameter1-><|Interpreter->String,Label->Parameter 1:|>,parameter2-><|Interpreter->Number,Label->Parameter 2:|>|>,AppearanceRules-><|Title->Enter parameters|>],Forms`FormFunction`PackagePrivate`values$51655)`

Comment: What version are you using? I'm on 13.2 with Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Mathematica 12.1